# Do we need a canonical question on common fglrx driver issues?

Tags: discussion

I am bringing this to the attention of the community as I am seeing a lot of questions on this topic. I myself have answered quite a few questions on this topic. See all these links:-

- [Why ubuntu is not detecting my AMD Radeon graphics?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440971/why-ubuntu-is-not-detecting-my-amd-radeon-graphics)
- [Which proprietary driver should I activate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442930/which-proprietary-driver-should-i-activate)
- [ATI Catalyst vs Distro Compatibility Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437395/ati-catalyst-vs-distro-compatibility-question)
- [Uninstalling "previous install of the fglrx driver"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445758/uninstalling-previous-install-of-the-fglrx-driver)
- [What video driver should I download?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437676/what-video-driver-should-i-download)
- [How to install the proprietary AMD graphic driver(fglrx) correctly via the AMD website?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434986/how-to-install-the-proprietary-amd-graphic-driverfglrx-correctly)
- [AMD Catalyst Driver installer failing at DKMS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240184/amd-catalyst-driver-installer-failing-at-dkms)
- [Can't install ATI proprietary drivers in 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202857/cant-install-ati-proprietary-drivers-in-12-10)

Hungry for more of such questions? Check out these tags and you will find a lot more :- https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ati and https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/fglrx

You must have noted that several of these questions are asking about the installation or troubleshooting and other similar issues. Some of the answers say about installing Synaptic, some about installing directly from terminal, some may refer to a certain PPA(like xorg-edgers) and some others like mine say about getting from the AMD website itself. This way of suggesting lot of methods to install itself confuses some users and they come up with questions like this https://askubuntu.com/questions/375727/cannot-get-ati-drivers-installed !

Also as a newbie to Ubuntu(I am just nearly 3 months old with regards to Ubuntu!), I feel my greatest problem with Ubuntu was getting the fglrx driver installed so that my graphic card would be correctly detected. From personal experience itself I must add that, that problem was made 'greatest' because of a missing centralized question in AskUbuntu on which every newbie's eyes would be caught, on that topic.

So I suppose we need a canonical question about fglrx drivers. But does the community suppose so?

**IMPORTANT UPDATE:-**

I just came to know that the community already has a canonical type of question for installation process!! See here :- [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-propetary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/126513#126513)   Way to go AU!!

So, now, does the community need a canonical question that answers common fglrx problems? Like low graphics mode, unity crash etc. in one question?

**PS :-**

I see that these questions here are answering some common problems :-

- [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error/)
- [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Do you guys know of some more common problems with fglrx like the above ones? If yes, then post them below....

Comment: Reading the titles, I dare to say that they are different questions.

Comment: @Braiam But probably a single Canonical question on installing, troubleshooting etc etc would have extinguished the need for all those questions..right?

Comment: NONONONO, mega questions that tries to address several issues at once is not helpful. 1 question for 1 issue that can be answered in 2 paragraph is enough. 1 for installing, one for each kind of problem, etc. Canonical questions that have several answers are not helpful and bury the useful information with noise.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-propetary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/126513#126513 we have that.

Comment: @Seth I have edited the question accordingly...

Comment: I would love to help in this part but I only have Nvidia cards ATM. Would have enjoyed making a definite guide. The link provided by Seth is actually one of the best for ATI installation.

Answer (score 7):

If there is a lot of overlap between a couple of very similar issues (driver selection and installation for example), that's probably a useful Q/A... But if you're writing dozens of paragraphs to cater to dozens of sub-issues, you should probably be creating (or improving) existing documentation on the Ubuntu Wiki.

Ask Ubuntu should have the answer to everything... Just not in one post. Otherwise I say we delete everything and start a "I have a question about Ubuntu"-megapost.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/installing-nvidia-drivers this answer seems to contradict what you say...

Comment: Copied from chat: And in my opinion that's far too broad. Luis originally wanted to have all graphics drivers under one roof. That sort of conglomeration just isn't useful outside of a documentation role.

Comment: ok. So shall i edit this question to ask about creating a CANON question that answers all fglrx install problems?

Comment: @Venki not **all** install problems. You got a specific problem, you get a specific question/answer that address it.

Comment: +1 for "I have a question about Ubuntu"-megapost. Let's have one **uber-mega-gigantic** question that answers everything. Literally everything.

Comment: @NathanOsman I'm not sure if you are being sarcastic or what.

Comment: @Braiam: I'm being silly, actually.